# Typescript Import External Module in Internal Module

Tags: knockout.js, module, typescript, amd

I need some help related with Typescript and how to use external modules in Internal Modules.

I want to store all my ViewModel code logic in the ViewModels internal module.

** HomePageViewModel.ts **

```
module ViewModels {
export class HomePageViewModel {
    constructor() {
        console.log('Creating HomePageViewModel');
    }

    public SayHello(): void {
        console.log('Hello from HomePageViewModel');
    }
}
}
```

** ViewModelFactories **

```
public static CreateHomePageViewModel(): ViewModels.HomePageViewModel {
    return new ViewModels.HomePageViewModel();
}
```

This is working correctly and I can compile and everything works fine at execution time.

Now if I add an import in HomePageViewModel (knockout for example)

```
import ko = require('knockout');
```

Typescript no longer compiles. The ViewModelFactories code is underline under Views and inform me that it 'Could Not Find symbol Views'.

How can I access the knockout module from within the ViewModel module?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can't mix both module types.

Your internal module is becoming external as soon as you require another external module.
You have to access knockout in an "internal" way: import it as a `<script>` in your starting HTML file (as you're probably already doing for your other files), then use the global `ko` variable.

Another solution is to make your modules external.

Comment: Isn't there any way around this ? I'm having trouble with this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47433240/cant-use-leaflet-plugins-in-typescript-namespaces

Answer (score 1):

You need to get "knockout.d.ts" file (or similar) with "ko.xxxxxx" definitions. You can obtain it from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/knockout.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/) or [github](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped).
After you will be able to write e.g.

```
var observable = ko.observable<number>(100);
```

in your TypeScript code. Of course you still need to include "knockout.x.x.x.js" file on your page.

May be you should use namspase, as described at the [TypeScript Documentation](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Modules%20in%20TypeScript):

Needless Namespacing

If you're converting a program from internal modules to external modules, it can be easy to end up with a file that looks like this:
shapes.ts

```
export module Shapes {
    export class Triangle { /* ... */ }
    export class Square { /* ... */ }
}
```

The top-level module here Shapes wraps up Triangle and Square for no reason. This is confusing and annoying for consumers of your module:
shapeConsumer.ts

```
import shapes = require('./shapes');
var t = new shapes.Shapes.Triangle(); // shapes.Shapes?
```

Comment: I already have the knockout.d.ts file. If I write "export module ViewModels". Everything is working fine and I can import knockout, but then the module is considered as an external module and I need to require it to access it. It also results in the module not loading the other files defining the module.

Comment: I checked the 'https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Modules%20in%20TypeScript' document, may be you need to specify relative path to the knockout, like 'import shapes = require('./shapes');' in the above mentioned doc?

Comment: May be you should use an import name to access knockout? 'import knockout = require('knockout'); var v = knockout.ko.observable();'?

Answer (score 0):

Your `HomePageViewModel` is defined in the `ViewModels` module—not the `Views` module.

```
public static CreateHomePageViewModel(): ViewModels.HomePageViewModel {
    return new ViewModels.HomePageViewModel();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for spotting this out, but this is not the problem unfortunately :(